# Display all lines of a log file where number value is greater than or equal to X

Tags: logfile

I have a log file (encoder.log) where I want to show all lines where the value is greater than or equal to a specific value. Here is an example of a line:

563.456: LDMP: flow #0 state=   READY (F)     192.168.1.50 bytes= 82757648 cwnd=158 avg_rtt= 179 peak_rtt= 250 timeoutcnt= 2523(3.66%) EchoSz=146 QUE=158 bitrate= 7473 Kbps [p/s=277 suggest_cwnd=49] rtt= 158

Example: I want to display any lines in the log file where the peak_rtt= 250.

I’ve tried several attempts to grep, awk or sed this but none are working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.